# Youtube Data API Video Upload Failing returning "uploadLimitExceeded"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the youtube data api to upload videos to a single youtube channel. We are currently uploading around 10 - 15 videos a day. We had requested a quota increase from 10000(default) to 50000 which got aproved. This worked seamlessly for 3-4 months but now we are facing this error:

> {\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.",\n        "domain": "youtube.video",\n        "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n

Our quota usage peaks at around 64% from what we can see in the cloud console and from what I've read on stackoverflow, this seems to not be related to quota usage. Can someone help me figure out what's going on here ?

Comment: This error doesnt have anything to do with quota.   This error is user based that user cant upload anymore videos.   Try switching to another user.